# "Argument 'BrowseController' is not a function, got undefined" in AngularJS 1.3.8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I was working on my AngularJS application and suddenly I received the error "Argument 'BrowseController' is not a function, got undefined" I undid all my changes and tried the answers supplied on here but the problem still remains.

Here is my app.js file

```
'use strict';

var app = angular
  .module('BikeShopApp', [
    'ngAnimate',    
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',    
    'firebase',
    'toaster',
    'angularMoment'
  ])
  .constant('FURL', 'contains url to my application')
  .run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, next, previous, error) {
      // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireAuth promise is rejected
      // and redirect the user back to the login page
      if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
        $location.path("/login");
      }
    });
  })  
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider      
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/browse.html',
        controller: 'BrowseController'
      })
      .when('/browse/:taskId', {
        templateUrl: 'views/browse.html',
        controller: 'BrowseController'     
      })
      .when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
        controller: 'AuthController'
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'AuthController'
      })

    .when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardController',
        resolve: {
          currentAuth: function(Auth) {
            return Auth.requireAuth();
          }
        }
      })

      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

and here is the main part of my browse.js controller

```
'use strict';

app.controller('BrowseController', function($scope, $routeParams, toaster, Task, Auth, Comment, Offer) {
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: Try changing app.controller('BrowseController',  .. to angular.module('BikeShopApp').controller('BrowseController',....

Comment: Hi Rohan, thanks for replying to my question, I have just figured out the problem which was an issue with a missing bracket at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this myself, as it turns out at the bottom of my code I was missing a bracket

This is what it as originally

```
Offer.acceptOffer($scope.selectedTask.$id, offerId, mechanicId.then(function() {
```

And here is the updated version where I have added the bracket which threw the entire error

```
Offer.acceptOffer($scope.selectedTask.$id, offerId, mechanicId).then(function() {
```